# I don't know how to get timestamp in mongodb

Tags: mongodb

I have a question.
When inserting or updatingOne in MongoDB, the input time is inserted using new Date().
However, when using new Date(), UTC time is recorded.
I live in Korea and I want to set the time zone to Korea.
What should I do?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do that. **All times in MongoDB are stored as UTC times.**

Usually the client application takes care to display the time as local time. If you need to preserve the input time zone, then you must store it separately in a dedicated field.

Then you can use for example [$dateToString](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/dateToString/) to **display** the time in desired time zone.

Comment: In this case, please accept the answer.

Comment: sorry, 
I haven't found an answer. By the way, do you know how to accept the answer?

Comment: Click on the light gray ✓